# Notification messaging when sending an invite

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, invite, facebook-requests

When sending an invite through the requests dialog using the JavaScript SDK, the resulting notification is worded "[App Name]:[User Name] invited you to try."

The JavaScript call to the requests api looks like:

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'apprequests',
    message: "You're Invited.",
    filters: ['app_non_users'],
}, requestCallback);
```

My understanding is that the message field is ignored for invites, though.

It seems like placing the name of the app at the end of the sentence in the invite would make more sense (i.e. "[User Name] invited you to try [App Name].")

Is there some mechanism by which I can change the wording of the invite.